# Add two ArrayList to one ArrayList of hashmaps

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I have two `ArrayList` and I want to make one `ArrayList` by adding them, both lists have same size

I am going to do it this way.

Is this optimized or can I make it better and efficient when the lists become large?

i.e.

```
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> imageFile= new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    imageFile.add(xy); 
    imageFile.add(ab);
    imageFile.add(cd);

    private ArrayList<MediaPlayer> musicFile= new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();

    musicFile.add(mm);
    musicFile.add(nn);
    musicFile.add(ll);

    private HashMap<Bitmap, MediaPlayer> mappedFiles= new HashMap<Bitmap, MediaPlayer>();

    mappedFiles.put(imageFile.get(i),musicFile.get(i))


    private ArrayList<HashMap<Bitmap, MediaPlayer>> imageMusic= new ArrayList<HashMap<Bitmap, MediaPlayer>>();

   imageMusic.add(mappedFiles);
```

Comment: "Optimized" depends on what you need.  Are there duplicates?  Same entries in both lists?  Do you want to get rid of them?  Does order matter?

Comment: @Makky I want to make arraylist of hashmaps from two different arraylists of same size.

Comment: Why an ArrayList of HashMaps? Are there other HashMaps you will be adding to the ArrayList later?

Comment: Yeah you are right I will add more hashmaps... to my arraylist of hashmaps.

Comment: Why multiple hashmaps? don't you want *one* hashmap with the images as keys to the music files? Do you need the lists alone, or are they just a mechanism to create the map?

Comment: @Bohemian I always get new image paths and their corresponding music file paths and then I download and cache images and music files in this box. Just think of it as a Box (`Arraylist`) of CD's (with label(image file) and track(music file ) (`Hashmap`))

Comment: @CPerkins Order matters and there are no duplicates that's why I have used ArrayList and I am editing the question to LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you don't want a map at all, you want classes and Lists:

```
public class Track {
    private final String name;
    private final MediaPlayer music;
    public Track (String name, MediaPlayer music) {
        this.name = name;
        this.music = music;
    }
    // getters omitted
}

public class CD {
    private final String name;
    private final BitMap image; 
    private final List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
    public CD (String name, BitMap image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }
    public List<Track> getTracks() {
        return tracks;
    } 
    // other getters omitted
}
```

Then

```
List<CD> cds = new List<CD>();
CD cd = new CD("Thriller", someBitMap);
cd.getTracks().add(new Track("I'm bad", someMusic));
cds.add(cd);
```

Comment: but how much complexity would my approach incur.

Comment: Well it's going to be harder for you as the programmer to figure out what is going on. That will lead to bugs and/or frustration. Keep things beat and orderly and you'll stay sane and build you software. This approach also lets you easily add more attributes like track length, track style, CD genre, etc etc. you approach would quickly become a mess IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Write a wrapper for Bitmap , and Media Player yourself

```
class Media {
   Bitmap bitmap;
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer
}
```

When you have to map bitmap and mediaplayer, create an object of this class and push them to an `ArrayList<Media>` ?

Why do you want to complicate by using HashMap of Bitmap of MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> imageFile = new ArrayList<String>();

        imageFile.add("XY");
        imageFile.add("ZZ");
        imageFile.add("YY");

        ArrayList<Integer> musicFile = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        musicFile.add(1);
        musicFile.add(2);
        musicFile.add(4);

        Map<List<String>, List<Integer>> fullMap = new HashMap<List<String>, List<Integer>>();
        fullMap.put(imageFile, musicFile);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need that structure (I don't understand what's the deal with the last `ArrayList`), then I think it's fairly optimized.

You don't have a way to easily create a Map out of two lists, so you'll have to cycle through them, since these are array lists, a very simple `for` will be quite explicit:

```
private HashMap<Bitmap, MediaPlayer> mappedFiles= new HashMap<Bitmap, MediaPlayer>();
for(int i=0; i<imageFile.size(); i++) {
    mappedFiles.put(imageFile.get(i), musicFile.get(i));
}
```